# Add Android Specific external library

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter

A short backstory, I am trying to use the flutter platform channels to run some platform specific code and return the results back to flutter.

I am trying to add some dependencies in my android build.gradle file however after I do so, there is no option to "rebuild" or "download" these dependencies like it used to show when developing pure java android applications.

Am I missing something? How to properly import external libraries to be used in the native code that I write when I call a platform channel method?

for example:
`compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'`

I can't find a build option in gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using command line or Terminal (on Mac), cd to your **android** folder and run this command: **./gradlew build** or **./gradlew assembleDebug**

Or you can also import/open the android project only (open android folder directly, instead of open flutter project folder)

Comment: This "works" but funny enough, the IDE still shows errors such as "cannot resolve symbol" even though it runs successfully. I am marking this as answered but do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Try: File > Invalidate caches/restart